# Given that the data features are all nominal; does it make any sense to apply PCA to the data?

Tags: pca

If PCA also helps to normalize the data, how a normalized data is going to be improved by PCA. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PCA does more than normalize the data (in fact, it only normalizes if whiten=True). It also projects into a different space using the n_components eigenvectors with maximal variation (largest eignevalues) - this can provide better performance for your classifier/clustering if your data is "stretched" along a particular dimension. See [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_3d.html#example-decomposition-plot-pca-3d-py) for more information.